# How to test a cookie was set correctly by a controller in play framework?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I am testing a controller using scalatest:

```
  "mycontroller" must {
    "redirect to homepage" when {
      "partner is full and no reg" in {
        val result: Future[Result] = MyController.myAction().apply(FakeRequest())
        status(result) mustBe SEE_OTHER
        result.futureValue.header.headers.getOrElse("Location", "") mustBe "/"
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to also test that a certain cookie was set. I could do it by "reverse engineering" the `SET_COOKIE` header, but I wondered if there's some helper code available for extracting a single cookie value?